# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception on employee database program

Tags: java, database, indexoutofboundsexception

I am very new to java and have been trying to get my bearings with it. I've been trying to write an proof of concept employee database. It all works fine until I enter the last employee condition, then I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is the code for both of my files. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EmployeeInterface 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of employees to register.");
        int employeeCount = Input.nextInt();
        Employee.setEmployeeNumber(employeeCount);
        String employeeFullName;
        String employeeAddress;
        String employeeDateOfHire;

        for(int x = 0; x <= employeeCount; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the full name of employee number " + (x + 1));
            Input.nextLine();
            employeeFullName = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the address of employee number " + (x + 1));
            employeeAddress = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the date of hire for employee " + (x + 1));
            employeeDateOfHire = Input.nextLine();

            Employee.employeeRegister(x, employeeFullName, employeeAddress, employeeDateOfHire);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second file:

```
public class Employee 
{
    private static int employeeCount;
    private static String employees[][] = new String[employeeCount][4];

    public static void setEmployeeNumber(int x)
    {
        employeeCount = x;
    }

    public static void employeeRegister(int employeeNumber, String employeeFullName, String address, String employeeHireDate)
    {
        employees[employeeNumber][0] = employeeFullName;
        employees[employeeNumber][1] = employeeFullName;
        employees[employeeNumber][2] = employeeFullName;
        employees[employeeNumber][3] = employeeFullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Proof of concept? How about to write GUI?

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= employeeCount; x++)
```

You're using `<=` rather than `<`. So if `employeeCount` is 3, you'll actually ask for the details of *4* employees, and use indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3 - but 3 is an invalid index for an array of size 3.

Your `setEmployeeCount` method is *also* broken - it changes the value of `employeeCount`, but doesn't reinitialize the array, so you'll always end up with an array of size 0. Given that you've said the code works until the final entry, I suspect this isn't a problem in your *real* code, as otherwise you'd get an exception on the very first entry.

That said, I would *strongly* recommend that you create a rather more useful `Employee` type, with private *instance* fields for number, name etc... then create a `List<Employee>`. (There's probably no point in it being stored via a static field in `Employee` either - what if you want two employee lists?)

Additionally, an `employeeHireDate` should be in some appropriately chronological type - not a string. (I'd suggest using `LocalDate` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as the built-in Java types for date/time types are awful.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers:

```
private static String employees[][] = new String[employeeCount][4];
```

employeeCount is immediately intialized as 0  and so is the array afterwards.

You need to reintialize your array after setting employeeCount.

Answer (score 0):

your loop is iterating 1 extra time. if employeeCount is 5 then loop iterates 6 times.
Try this instead

```
for(int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception
```

because you are trying to access the 1 index more which doesn't exist by using `<=` instead of `<` only

use `for(int x = 0; x < employeeCount; x++)`

instead of

```
for(int x = 0; x <= employeeCount; x++)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other answers:

In the method `setEmployeeNumber(int x)`, you only change the variable `employeeCount`. What's missing here is to resize the array wherein you store the employees:

```
employees[][] = new String[employeeCount][4];
```